# Nuxt.js store state issue. Wrong state visiting homepage

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, nuxt.js, store

I have a problem with store behavior in nuxt.js app.
When i visit home page fetch fills store with initial values. Next time i visit some other pages and make changes in store state. When I back to the home store state is proper (with changes), but when next time I visit other pages store state looks like initial values.

Can anybody tell me whats going on ?

Comment: i think the problem is that every time you visit the home page you fetch the initial data that reset the state, i can't  say more without seeing your code

Comment: Tough to debug without further info.